# Using socket.io-client in angular-cli@webpack

Tags: angular, socket.io, webpack, angular-cli

I'm tying to use socket.io in my Angular 2 application, and I'm not having much luck getting access to it from within my Angular 2 application. Here's some information about my setup:

Angular 2: rc.5
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2
Node: 6.2.2
OS: Linux x64

I've got socket.io installed via npm and typings, and I see it in my node_modules directory, but that Angular 2 application can't seem to resolve:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
```

I've seen a posts about how to address this using Webpack and its config files, but those don't seem to exist for an application generated with angular-cli@webpack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need should be the following:

npm:

```
npm install socket.io-client --save
```

import in your component.ts/service.ts

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
```

a dummy module declaration in your typings.d.ts:

```
declare module 'socket.io-client' {
  var e: any;
  export = e;
}
```

I don't know if typings are available, but you can try `npm i @types/socket.io-client --save-dev` instead of just declaring a dummy.

Any webpack config should be taken care of by angular-cli.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've included these steps in my project and it seems to be working. At least to the point where I can include socket.io in my service and create a socket, and things don't blow up! I'm going to make an alternative to my current polling/http service that uses socket.io and see if it all hangs together. Again, thanks for your help!!